# Vaadin DataField

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I want to have PopupDataField for changing the date in my form, and separatly changing hours and minutes by NativeSelect components. So then I want to have some date which has year, month and day from PopupDataField and time from those NativeSelects. I dont know how to save this "date" bc when i call

```
popupDateField.getValue()
```

[image]
I'm reciving whole data with hours and minutes, often different from this on NativeSelects.
I was trying to disable saving the hour by

```
setResolution(Resolution.DAY);
```

but it's not working.

I dont know how to do this, can someone help me?

I want to have some field data- where ll be year, month day from DateField and hour, minutes from NativeSelects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PopupDateField](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/PopupDateField.html) will always return [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object as its value hence you will receive from this component hours and minutes. The solution is simple - just ignore them. Construct your `Date` or [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) object from the all components not just `PopupDateField`.

[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

```
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
    PopupDateField popupDateField = new PopupDateField();
    NativeSelect hoursSelect = new NativeSelect("Hours");
    for(int i=0; i<24; i++){
        hoursSelect.addItem(i);
    }
    NativeSelect minutesSelect = new NativeSelect("Minutes");
    for(int i=0; i<60; i++){
        minutesSelect.addItem(i);
    }

    class MyValueChangeListener implements ValueChangeListener{
        public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
            LocalDate date = popupDateField.getValue().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
            int year = date.getYear();
            int month = date.getMonth().getValue();
            int days = date.getDayOfMonth();
            int minutes = minutesSelect.getValue() == null ? 0 : (int) minutesSelect.getValue();
            int hours = hoursSelect.getValue() == null ? 0 : (int) hoursSelect.getValue();
            System.out.println(LocalDateTime.of(year,  month, days, hours, minutes));
        }
    }
    ValueChangeListener listener = new MyValueChangeListener();
    minutesSelect.addValueChangeListener(listener);
    hoursSelect.addValueChangeListener(listener);
    popupDateField.addValueChangeListener(listener);

    setContent(layout);

    layout.addComponent(popupDateField);
    layout.addComponent(hoursSelect);
    layout.addComponent(minutesSelect);
}
```

You can also extend `PopupDateField` class by adding `getLocalDate` method which will convert `Date` to `LocalDate`.

Comment: Thanks, You helped me a lot!